# elegant means of switching between S3 platforms with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have some code that uses boto3 and I also have the requirement to be able to switch between using AWS S3 and an S3 compatible on-premises storage platform, this is the code I use for connecting to the on-premises storage platform:

```
s3 = boto3.resource(service_name          = 's3',
                    use_ssl               = False,
                    aws_access_key_id     = aws_key,
                    aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret,
                    endpoint_url          = aws_endpoint)
```

The code for establishing a connection to AWS would look something like this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource(service_name          = 's3',
                    aws_access_key_id     = aws_key,
                    aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret,
                    region_name           = aws_region)
```

I obtain the various parameters that I pass into boto3.resource from environment variables, I really want to avoid code that uses the logic of say:

```
if os.getenv("AWS_REGION") is not None:
  s3 = boto3.resource(service_name          = 's3',
                      use_ssl               = False,
                      aws_access_key_id     = aws_key,
                      aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret,
                      endpoint_url          = aws_endpoint)
.
.
.
```

Is there an elegant way of switching between platforms with s3.resource or in fact anything in boto3 ?, would I be better off using boto3.session and having different .credentials profiles for AWS and my on-premises appliance ?

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

Comment: Hardcoding credentials is a very bad practice. Profiles are much better.

Comment: I'm not using hard coded credentials in the real code, per the question I'm picking these up from environment variables, I've used the code in the question purely in the best interests of brevity, but to your point - I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

As users of AWS S3 who are more advanced than I will probably already know, you can access AWS S3 via a URL endpoint, the naming convention of which is:

```
protocol://service-code.region-code.amazonaws.com
```

Therefore, is the region is us east 2, you would use the following:

```
http://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

TL;DR there is no need to switch between using an AWS region and endpoint URL in your boto3 code, it will work equally well with a URL for an appliance/software defined storage platform or a URL for the relevant AWS region.